# SSH out from Docker Container to server on LAN

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an app that generates image files running in a Docker container.
Once the image is generated I want to copy it to another server on my LAN.

I'm trying to use SCP to a static IP on my LAN, but the container can't see it. How can I expose the LAN IP to my container?

Comment: you can use `--network=host`or better `docker cp` to localhost then `scp`

Comment: have you exposed ssh port?

Comment: if I bind port 22:22 in the docker-compose file it complains that the address is already in use

Comment: `I'm trying to use SCP to a static IP on my LAN, but the container can't see it`, what does this mean, the container indeed could visit the external static ip. Please show what you did, and what's the error.

Comment: if you have a progress on this one which does not include `--network=host` please update your post :)

Comment: posted my solution below, although I took a slightly different route in the end. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Posting my solution here in case it helps someone else

My problem was how to copy a generated file from Docker contained app to a LAN machine.

The solution I found was to use the Samba share Docker here:
https://hub.docker.com/r/dperson/samba/

My app shares a volume with the Samba container, and my LAN machine connects to the Shared Samba directory.  Its much more robust than using ssh, and seems much less complicated than using bridge network IMO

Answer (score -2):

You will need to bind the ports using -p command with docker. If the port is already in use, try a different port. So: `docker run -p 22:24` And if that complains again what you need to do is see whats running on port 22. You can do that with `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` OR for specific ports: `sudo lsof -i:22`

Comment: if you bind port 22 of the host you wont be able to ssh to it till the docker container is stopped

Comment: You don’t need the `docker run -p` option to make outbound connections from a container.